# Monitor does not turn on until reset

Tags: display, troubleshooting

I have a system with an ATI 4870 hooked up to a Samsung P2350 using DVI. My motherboard is a GA-EP45 DS4P with the latest BIOS.

The situation is:

```
I turn on my PC (with the power switch)
I get a blank screen
I hit reset and the PC boots up normally, i.e. the monitor turns on and
```

This has been the case for a couple of months (Was away for a while, came back and it was the same case). I was hoping the situation would somehow fix itself but alas, nothing.

I have tried numerous settings in the BIOS (Combinations of different settings of the ACPI and power saving options) and have tried different cables.

Has anyone experienced this before? I don't know where to go from here. It is pretty infuriating because it means I can't put my computer to sleep, as the monitor won't come on.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: does turning the monitor off and on do it?

Comment: My Samsung p2450 turns itself on in the middle of night.

Comment: are you using HDMI?

Comment: truning monitor off doesn't fix it. hdmi = yes

Comment: I was just curious I have a 4750(I believe), and have the same issue every now and then. It only started happening when I moved from DVI to HDMI

Comment: Hm no wait I have DVI. Sorry was thinking of the difference between VGA and DVI. Sorry for the confusion. I'll fix my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for firmware/driver updates for your ATI 4870

To further test

1. Do you have an on board graphics card? Test it with that and see if you have the same results
2. Try a different monitor.

Comment: I don't have onboard graphics but I will try with a different computer and laptop tomorrow. Thanks for the help so far!